# Fix compared data and return line number and data

Tags: python

I have typed a program to compare vehicle A price (v_priceA) to various other vehicle prices in a carprices.txt text file which are in a new line.

The result should be a new text called highprices.txt file with all the prices greater than the price of Vehicle A in a newline and the associated line number from carprices.txt

My problem is am able to generate two text files that has the line number of the greater file and another with the greater price, instead of the greater price itself and line number together. I need to fix this.

Vehicle A price: 2500.50

```
v_priceA = 2500.50
a_file = 'carprices.txt'
with open(a_file, 'r') as document:
        values = [x for x, value in enumerate(document) if float(value) > v_priceA]

new_file = open('highpriceposition.txt', 'w')
for x in values:
    new_file.write(str(x) + '\n')
new_file.close()



a_file = 'carprices.txt'
with open(a_file, 'r') as document:
    values = [value for value in document if float(value) > v_priceA] 

with open('highprice.txt', 'w') as f:
    for x in values:
        f.write(str(x)+'\n')
```

positionprice.txt

```
2 2900.00
3 3500.50
5 25000.30
6 45000.50
```

Comment: You can iterate over the tuples created by "enumerate" and split them into two variables to have position and value together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write to the new file `new_file.write()` you need to pass it both the line number and price. I.E.

```
v_priceA = 2500.50
a_file = 'carprices.txt'
output_file = 'highprices.txt'


with open(a_file, 'r') as document:
    with open(output_file, 'w') as new_file:
        for line, price in enumerate(document):
            if float(price) > v_priceA:
                new_file.write(str(line) + " " + str(price))
                # See how I pass both in here?
```

It's important to know that whenever you `open()` a file in python as write `"w"` it's going to erase whatever is in that file *before* writing to it. (There's an append option if your interested).
[Docs for Open](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).

Notice how I only open the output file once in the above code? That *should* help.

Now on to how `enumerate` works. It takes an [iterable object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration)
and for each item in that iterable returns a tuple of `(itemIndex, item)` with at least one very important exception it basically the succinct equivalent of:

```
def myEnumerate(iterableParameter):
    i = 0
    outPutList = []
    while i < len(iterableParameter):
        outPutList += (i, iterableParameter[i])
    return outPutList
```

The important exception is that `enumerate` creates a generator where as the above creates a list. See [further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension).

Comment: Thank you. Actually i had written 'a' forgot to update it here. It's not working. The output is empty.

Comment: shucks. `if float(value)` should be `if float(price)`. I updated the code.

Comment: The code is not working. I don't know why I am not getting an output.

Comment: Fixed it. `line, price` needed to be swapped. It was comparing the `line` number to `v_priceA` and since it was always less, it never wrote.

Comment: Thank you :) Works perfectly. Do you have a explanation of how enumerate works?

Comment: @lara_g1999 see edit for an explanation of `enumerate`.